# How to update my vs code theme extension after publish

Tags: vscode-extensions

I was published my vs code theme in vs code marketplace.
But How I update my vs code theme? I need update it.
Please help me.

I browse on internet, but I don't see any solution. So please Ans my question.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What about publishing a new version of it?

Comment: I will update it; I will add logo and need edit theme.